# I want to replace $APP_DIR with APP/DIR using sed command (replace "$" with "/")

Tags: sed

I want to replace $APP_DIR with APP/DIR using sed command
tried this

```
sed -e 's/$APP_DIR /APP/DIR/g'
```

But it is giving error

Comment: how do I escape the '/' character

Comment: You can use a different separator like `+`, e.g. `echo '$APP_DIR' | sed -e 's+$APP_DIR+/APP/DIR+g`